# How to connect to Cloud SQL from Cloud Shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-shell

I'd like to use the Cloud Shell to run database migrations on my 2nd gen Cloud Sql instance.

I found an [example in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/examples#manage_cloud_sql_data) for how to connect using `gcloud`. But when I run the command Im getting an error:

```
$ gcloud beta sql connect my-instance --user=root
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.connect) Invalid instance property.
```

But, even if this does work Im not sure how to connect from my python script that performs my migrations. What connection string would I use? Would I need to manually whitelist the Cloud Shell IP for access?

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

The instructions above did not work, it was showing another message.

The first time you'll need to run the command below:

`gcloud beta sql connect <instance id> --project <project id>:us-central1 --user root`

Also, I switch to my project in the console:

`gcloud config set project <project id>`

However, I am now getting another error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.connect) The client is not authorized to make this request.`

I guess I'll need to allow the clients...

**Another Edit re Allowing Clients**

To finally connect to the DB I had install [Google SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-client#connect-proxy).

I set it up with FUSE (I use a Mac). After opening a connection following the instructions in the Google Docs. I was able to connect via the mysql command line.

`$ mysql -u root -p -S <localtion of cloud sql proxy folder>/<project id>:us-central1:<db instance id>`

**Original**

Just figured this one out. Here's how to do it:

1. Click on the instance you want to connect
2. In the `Overview` section, scroll down to `Properties`.
3. In `Properties` you will see `Instance connection name`. It will look something like `<your project>:us-central1:<instance name>`

Use that in the command:

`$ gcloud beta sql connect <your project>:us-central1:<instance name> --user root`

Comment: The connect command in gcloud does not take connection strings using ':'s.  Run: gcloud sql instances list to get the ids of the instances you can connect to and simply provide the raw name to the connect command.

Comment: @Mark the above worked for me... with the ":", and I also needed for the SQL [driver](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql). However... I haven't tried your command, might be easier! Thanks!

Comment: for sql server ?

Answer (score -1):

You should set your project first with : `gcloud config set project projectname`

After that you can do again : `gcloud sql instances describe my_instance_name`